# How can I change opacity of area mark or specifically, how do I define opacity of gradient stops?

Tags: vega-lite

In [this example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/area_gradient), how can I change the opacity of the area mark? I am trying to change the opacity of the area to 1 (fully opaque).

Adding `"opacity": 1` or `"fillOpacity": 1` to `mark` does not seem to work. On the other hand, while defining [Gradient](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/types.html#gradient), one can only define a `color` for a `stop` but not the `opacity`.

Edit: [dominic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214950/dominik)'s answer below can be used to define opacity of gradient stops. However,
there seems to be a bug for defining opacity of Area marks: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this format for colors `rgba(R, G, B, A)` where A is the alpha.

```
"color": {
  "x1": 1,
  "y1": 1,
  "x2": 1,
  "y2": 0,
  "gradient": "linear",
  "stops": [
    {
      "offset": 0,
      "color": "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0)"
    },
    {
      "offset": 1,
      "color": "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

To set the opacity to 1, you can use an encoding

```
"opacity": {
  "value": 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps to define the transparency in gradient. However, The area chart still has some transparency even through I'm setting alpha to 1: https://imgur.com/a/g2mvqBl